# mod_rewrite - how to rewrite an URL?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Is there a way to rewrite an URL like

> http://mydomain.com/getProduct.php?id=1&mode=simple

in

> http://mydomain.com/products/1/simple

using `mod_rewrite` in Apache2?

Comment: Didn't Joel write an article about this? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ " If you keep seeing the same form of questions, whether it’s mod_rewrite rules on Server Fault" Oh the justification he must be feeling now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule /products/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) /getProduct.php?id=$1&mode=$2
```

For more information search google for mod_rewrite tutorials.