# Rewrite rule for this

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help me for this mod_rewrite result

how i can get using .htaccess

```
http://www.domain.com/artist.php?userid=2&name=username
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/saquib
```

please help

Comment: learn from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660433/mod-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-an-url/4660464 or ask google

Comment: and your both urls have nothing in common. What do you want to rewrite? Just forward it!

Comment: I want every user have there username at the end of URL for there profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily rewrite requests like `/saquib` internally to `/artist.php?name=saquib` by using a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]+$ artist.php?name=$0
```

But the problem with your example is the user ID that cannot be obtained from the requested URI path. So unless you use a path that also contains the user ID (e.g. `/2-saquib`), the user names need to be unique to identify the users just by their user name.

By the way: You should think about using a [unique path prefix as some kind of namespace](http://warpspire.com/posts/url-design/) for your users like `/users/…`.