# Can I hide a portion of my URL?

Tags: php, jquery, http-headers

I asked a simialr question earlier about using jquery and hashtags but what I really need to do is after a successful login redirect the user to the home page (home.php) Ideally I want to load my header with my menu only once and then update my main div tag with the contents of home.  This will let me load the menu bar just once and not after every page load.  I'm currently calling the home page like so:

```
if(isset($success) {
    header('Location: menu.php?home');
    exit();
}
```

Is it possible to hide the menu.php portion of the URL to the end user or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: rename `menu.php` to `index.php`, `Location: http://www.example.com/?home`.

Comment: You can use .htaccess file to rewrite a URL. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660433/mod-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-an-url

Comment: The HTML for the header is a little bit of HTML and thus tiny. Any images, css, js, etc will be cached. Don't worry about reloading it.

Comment: I'm guessing here, you don't want to reload the page... you want to dynamically load the content from home using ajax?

In that case, look at using something like Backbone.js for building your URLs. But there's a fair bit of knowledge to get from here to there.

Comment: See this Post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559186/php-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to hide the menu.php portion of the URL to the end user?

No.

> is there a better way?

You can use a mod_rewrite rule to rewrite /home to /menu.php?home.

Comment: this might work...is mod_rewrite able to go the other way, meaning if a user bookmarks the page: http://example.com/home it will call http://example.com/menu.php?home  ?

Comment: Yes, that was the example I intended to convey.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe look at apaches [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). [Tutorial](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

what about renaming menu.php to index.php & using it like

```
if(isset($success)) {
    header('Location: /?home');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I considered that but my current index.php page is checking the login etc and calling my new header after a successful login.