# How to change my url to user friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite - how to rewrite an URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660433/mod-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-an-url)

Hi can anyone of you suggest me on how to redirect my page http://testsite.com/about.php to http://testsite.com/about/ by using ht access rewrite rules,without using any query string in the page url I need to rewrite it.

Comment: Did you try searching? This must have been asked a million times

Comment: Imagine I ask this question to you. Could you work out what I wanted, and how you'd go about doing it? You'd downvote me too for not showing any effort, I'd imagine. **You need to put more detail into this question.** The amount of times I have to say that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to achieve.
The following will serve about.php for all requests to `http://example.com/about/`. The user won't notice anything. Is this what you want to do?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You could very simply use [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) to achieve such a result

```
Options MultiViews
```